# Having issues with displaying a picture and using an int in my game

Tags: java

I'm pretty much learning how to program, I understand most of the things I'm doing but I recently got stuck and have no way of fixing this problem. First of all I want to display a picture on my JFrame and second I want to see if my program detects mouse-movement, I do that by simply printing it's current x and y coordinates in my frameupdater:

Core class:

```
package B0ss;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class B0ssCore extends JPanel implements KeyListener, MouseListener {

    //Subclasses
    MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();

    public void updateMainMenu() throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            repaint();
            mainMenu.drawMainMenu(getWidth(), getHeight());

            System.out.println(mouse_X, mouse_Y);

            Thread.sleep(20);
        }
    }   

    //Keyboard
    public void keyPressed( KeyEvent e) { }
    public void keyReleased ( KeyEvent e) { }
    public void keyTyped ( KeyEvent e ) { }

    //Mouse
    public void mousePressed ( MouseEvent e ) {
        int mouse_Y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
        int mouse_X = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
    }
    public void mouseReleased ( MouseEvent e ) { }
    public void mouseClicked ( MouseEvent e ) { }
    public void mouseEntered ( MouseEvent e ) { }
    public void mouseExited ( MouseEvent e ) { }

    //Paint
    @Override
    public void paint ( Graphics g ) {
        super.paint(g);

        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        mainMenu.paint(g2D);
    }




    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Ba0ssGame");

        B0ssCore gameCore = new B0ssCore();

        gameCore.setSize(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());

        frame.add(gameCore);

        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        gameCore.updateMainMenu();
    }

}
```

Subclass for my main menu:

```
package B0ss;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class MainMenu {

    public void drawMainMenu( int width, int height) {

    }

    public void paint ( Graphics2D g2D ) {
        Image smiley = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\Shimolis\\Desktop");
        g2D.drawImage(smiley, 0, 0, 50, 50, 0, 0, smiley.getWidth(null), smiley.getHeight(null), null);

        g2D.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);

    }

}
```

It's not that I want you to fix my code. I want to understand why I get an error on the ints mouse_x and mouse_y in my updateMainMenu(). I've also looked up on different ways to dispay a picture, but it's too confusing since I don't understand what an imageObserver is, I've tried reading about it but I simply do not get it. So I tried setting it to null, is that an issue?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I made such a bad mistake (I didn't finish the path for the picture), sorry for the post. I realized the problem with the picture, but the issue with mouse_x and mouse_y still persists.

Answer (score 2):

Well there are several problems in your code. Just from a brief look at your code I can say that your `mouse_x` and `mouse_y` are local to `mousePressed ( MouseEvent e )` method, declare them outside of the method so you can use them in your `updateMainMenu()` method.

Another thing is you are implementing `Listeners` without actually using them, the values you assign to `mouse_x` and `mouse_y` are screen coordinates which are not relative to your `JPanel`.

Add a `constructor` to your `B0ssCore` class and add the `Listeners` you implement, something like:

```
public B0ssCore(){
    super();
    addMouseListener(this);
}
```

and change the `public void mousePressed ( MouseEvent e )` to something like:

```
public void mousePressed ( MouseEvent e ) {
    // don't forget to declare mouse_x and mouse_y at the class level
    mouse_Y = e.getX(); // relative to container coordinates
    mouse_X = e.getX();
}
```

There are other issues in your code. For example this:

```
while (true) {
    repaint();
    mainMenu.drawMainMenu(getWidth(), getHeight());
    System.out.println(mouse_X, mouse_Y);
    Thread.sleep(20);
}
```

looks suspicious. There are a lot of things that can be done much better in your code but I guess that's how you learn so Good luck.

Comment: That helped me alot, thanks! But shouldn't I add the mouseListener in my frame instead? Atleast for my keyListener, since I need to set my programs focus to the frame, is it something similar with a mouseListener?

Comment: Well you can but judging by your code all your operations on the Input are done inside the `JPanel` so no, don't add the `Listeners` to the `JFrame` and just call `requestFocus();` in the `B0ssCore` `constructor` for the `KeyListeners` to trigger.

Comment: @Joseph Generally MouseListener isn't as fussy as KeyListener, but you should be using key bindings instead

Comment: you should definitely do what MadProgrammer suggested.